# Sparse matrix multiplication using linked lists

Tags: c++, matrix

I have an assignment which requires students to conduct matrix multiplication given inputs of dimension mxn followed by the number of nonzero elements on each row. For example, the input

```
4 5
3 3 5 4 0
3 5 4 7 0
0
2 2 3 6 0
```

Represents the matrix

```
0 0 3 0 4
0 0 5 7 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 2 6 0 0
```

So far I have written this implementation of linked lists:

```
//LinkedList.h
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ListNode
{
    int val;
    ListNode* next;

    ListNode() : val(0), next(NULL) {};
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {};

    friend class LinkedList;
};

class LinkedList
{

public:
    LinkedList();
    void Push_back(int x);
    void Push_front(int x);
    void Insert(int index, int x);
    void Delete(int index);
    void Reverse();
    void Swap(int index_1, int index_2);
    void Print();
    int Find(int);
    ~LinkedList();

private:
    ListNode* Head; //first
    ListNode* Tail;
};
```

```
//LinkedList.cpp
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
    // Constructor
    Head = NULL;
}

void LinkedList::Push_back(int x) {
    // TODO : Insert a node to the end of the linked list, the node¡¦s value is x.
    ListNode* temp = new ListNode(x);

    if (Head ==0) {
        Head = temp;
        return;
    }

    ListNode* current = Head;
    while (current->next != 0) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = temp;
}

void LinkedList::Push_front(int x) {
    if (!Head) {
        Head = new ListNode(x);
        return;
    }
    ListNode* temp = new ListNode(x);

    temp->next = Head;
    Head = temp;
}

void LinkedList::Insert(int index, int x) {
    // TODO : Insert a node to the linked list at position ¡§index¡¨, the node's
    // value is x. The index of the first node in the linked list is 0.
    
    ListNode* temp = new ListNode(x);
    temp->val = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    
    if (Head == NULL) {
        Head = temp;
    }
    else if (index == 0) {
        temp->next = Head;
        Head = temp;
    }
    else {
        ListNode* cur = Head;
        int d = 1;
        while (cur != NULL) {
            if (d == index) {
                temp->next = cur->next;
                cur->next = temp;
                break;
            }
            cur = cur->next;
            d++;
        }
    }
}

void LinkedList::Delete(int index) {
    // TODO : Remove the node with index ¡§index¡¨ in the linked list.
    if (Head == NULL)
        return;

    ListNode* temp = Head;

    // If head needs to be removed
    if (index == 0) {
        Head = temp->next;
        temp = 0;
        return;
    }

    // previous node of the node to be deleted
    for (int i = 0; temp != NULL && i < index - 1; i++) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
        
    // If position is more than number of nodes
    if (temp == NULL || temp->next == NULL)
        return;

    // Node temp->next is the node to be deleted
    // Store pointer to the next of node to be deleted
    ListNode* next = temp->next->next;

    // Unlink the node from linked list
    free(temp->next); // Free memory

    // Unlink the deleted node from list
    temp->next = next;

}

void LinkedList::Reverse() {
    // TODO : Reverse the linked list.
    // Example :
    //
    // Original List : 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> NULL
    // Updated List  : 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> NULL

    if (Head == 0 || Head->next == 0) {
        return;
    }

    ListNode *previous = 0;
    ListNode *current = Head;
    ListNode *preceding = Head->next;

    while (preceding != 0) {
        current->next = previous;
        previous = current;
        current = preceding;
        preceding = preceding->next;
    }

    current->next = previous;
    Head = current;
}

void LinkedList::Swap(int index_1, int index_2) 
{
    // TODO : Swap two nodes in the linked list
    // Example : 
    // index_1 : 1   ,  index_2 : 3
    // 
    // Original List : 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> NULL
    // Updated List  : 1 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> NULL
    
    if (index_1 == index_2) return;
    int value_1 = Find(index_1);
    int value_2 = Find(index_2);

    Delete(index_1);
    Insert(index_1, value_2);
    Delete(index_2);
    Insert(index_2, value_1);
    
}

void LinkedList::Print() {
    cout << "List: ";
    // TODO : Print all the elements in the linked list in order.
    if (Head == NULL) {
        cout << "List empty." << endl;
    }

    ListNode* current = Head;
    while (current != 0) {
        cout << current->val << " ";
        current = current->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int LinkedList::Find(int index)
{

    ListNode* current = Head;

    // the index of the node we're currently
    // looking at
    int count = 0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (count == index) {
            return (current->val);
        }
        else {
            count++;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    while (Head) {
        ListNode* temp = Head;
        Head = Head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

I am trying to construct sparse matrices based on the algorithm in E. Horowitz's *Fundamentals of Data Structures, Revised Edition* though I am having a hard time understanding how matrix operations work with no use of vector/array. Where should I start?

Comment: Why do you need your own linked list? Is that a requirement in your assignment?

Comment: FYI -- `int main() { LinkedList list1; list1.Push_back(1); LinkedList list2 = list1; }` -- You now have a double-free runtime error on termination of the program.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, it is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for telling me, would initializing the tail and the head both solve this issue effectively?

Comment: @P.Y.C. You need to write a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator for `LinkedList`.  See [the rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and go to the **Managing Resources** section of that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only really need to define `Insert` and `Multiply`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
  int value;
  int row_position;
  int column_position;
  Node* next;
};

void Insert(Node** head, int row, int col, int value) {
  Node* new_node = new Node();
  new_node->value = value;
  new_node->row_position = row;
  new_node->column_position = col;
  new_node->next = *head;
  *head = new_node;
}

void Multiply(Node* a, Node* b, Node** result) {
  Node *ptr_a, *ptr_b;
  for (ptr_a = a; ptr_a != nullptr; ptr_a = ptr_a->next) {
    for (ptr_b = b; ptr_b != nullptr; ptr_b = ptr_b->next) {
      if (ptr_a->column_position == ptr_b->row_position) {
        int row = ptr_a->row_position;
        int col = ptr_b->column_position;
        int sum = 0;
        Node* ptr = *result;
        bool found = false;
        // Check if the position already has a value
        while (ptr != nullptr) {
          if (ptr->row_position == row && ptr->column_position == col) {
            ptr->value += ptr_a->value * ptr_b->value;
            found = true;
            break;
          }
          ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        // If not found, insert new value
        if (!found) {
          sum = ptr_a->value * ptr_b->value;
          Insert(result, row, col, sum);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void PrintMatrix(Node* head, int rows, int cols) {
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      Node* temp = head;
      bool found = false;
      while (temp != nullptr) {
        if (temp->row_position == i && temp->column_position == j) {
          std::cout << temp->value << " ";
          found = true;
          break;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
      }
      if (!found) {
        std::cout << "0 ";
      }
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}

void ReadMatrix(Node** head, int& rows, int& cols) {
  std::cin >> rows >> cols;
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    while (true) {
      int col, value;
      std::cin >> col;
      if (col == 0) break; // A col value of 0 indicates the end of input for the current row
      std::cin >> value;
      Insert(head, i, col - 1, value); // Adjust column index to be 0-based
    }
  }
}

void DeleteList(Node* head) {
  while (head != nullptr) {
    Node* temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete temp;
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
int main() {
  Node* a = nullptr;
  Node* b = nullptr;
  int rows_a, cols_a, rows_b, cols_b;
  std::cout << "Enter matrix A:" << '\n';
  ReadMatrix(&a, rows_a, cols_a);
  std::cout << "Matrix A (" << rows_a << "x" << cols_a << "):" << '\n';
  PrintMatrix(a, rows_a, cols_a);
  std::cout << "Enter matrix B:" << '\n';
  ReadMatrix(&b, rows_b, cols_b);
  std::cout << "Matrix B (" << rows_b << "x" << cols_b << "):" << '\n';
  PrintMatrix(b, rows_b, cols_b);
  if (cols_a != rows_b) {
    std::cout << "Matrices cannot be multiplied: incompatible dimensions." << '\n';
    DeleteList(a);
    DeleteList(b);
    return 1;
  }
  Node* result = nullptr;
  Multiply(a, b, &result);
  std::cout << "Resultant Matrix (" << rows_a << "x" << cols_b << "):" << '\n';
  PrintMatrix(result, rows_a, cols_b);
  DeleteList(a);
  DeleteList(b);
  DeleteList(result);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter matrix A:
4 5
3 3 5 4 0
3 5 4 7 0
0
2 2 3 6 0
Matrix A (4x5):
0 0 3 0 4 
0 0 5 7 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 2 6 0 0 
Enter matrix B:
5 2
1 8 2 7 0
1 6 0
2 5 0
0
1 3 2 4 0
Matrix B (5x2):
8 7 
6 0 
0 5 
0 0 
3 4 
Resultant Matrix (4x2):
12 31 
0 25 
0 0 
12 30
```

Comment: Looks like an O(N^6) algorithm to me.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Is there a way to do this in o(lmn) time for two matrices of size lxm, mxn ?

Comment: Thank you very much, this answered my question well! Is there a reason you did not calculate row and column count to check for compatibility in the Multiply function itself but rather in main()? Asking because I am trying to implement an Add() function using your Node structure but there seems to be a runtime error: https://pastebin.com/n7Av6769

Comment: @P.Y.C. You may want to keep the matrix as a list of rows where each row is a sorted list of occupied column positions, that is, pretty much the same as it is represented in the input. You also need to implement the transpose operation. Then O(lnm) multiplication is straightforward.