# Implementing sparse matrix addition by linked lists

Tags: c++, matrix

A while ago I asked a question regarding an assignment which required matrix multiplication function and a custom linked list structure. A [user answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506293/sparse-matrix-multiplication-using-linked-lists/77506424?noredirect=1#comment136643318_77506424) provided me a very helpful struct which I found much simpler than my original one. Out of interest I attempted to implement matrix addition and subtraction functions using this struct. My current addition function is very verbose and its outputs are always incorrect.

What might I change to achieve correct matrix addition/subtraction?

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    int row_position;
    int column_position;
    Node* next;
};

void Insert(Node** head, int row, int col, int value) {
    Node* new_node = new Node();
    new_node->value = value;
    new_node->row_position = row;
    new_node->column_position = col;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;

void Add(Node* a, Node* b, Node** result) {
    Node* ptr_a, * ptr_b;
    ptr_a = a;
    ptr_b = b;
    while (ptr_a != NULL && ptr_b!= NULL) {
        if (ptr_a->row_position == ptr_b->row_position) {
            if (ptr_a->column_position == ptr_b->column_position) {
                Node* ptr = *result;
                ptr->row_position = ptr_a->row_position;
                ptr->column_position = ptr_a->column_position;
                ptr->value = ptr_a->value + ptr_b->value;
                ptr->next = NULL;
                Insert(result, ptr->row_position, ptr->column_position, ptr->value);
                ptr_a->next;
                ptr_b->next;
            }
            if (ptr_a->column_position < ptr_b->column_position) {
                Node* ptr = *result;
                ptr->row_position = ptr_a->row_position;
                ptr->column_position = ptr_a->column_position;
                ptr->value = ptr_a->value;
                Insert(result, ptr->row_position, ptr->column_position, ptr->value);
                ptr_a->next;
            }
            else {
                Node* ptr = *result;
                ptr->row_position = ptr_b->row_position;
                ptr->column_position = ptr_b->column_position;
                ptr->value = ptr_b->value;
                Insert(result, ptr->row_position, ptr->column_position, ptr->value);
                ptr_b->next;
            }

            if (ptr_a->row_position < ptr_b->row_position) {
                Node* ptr = *result;
                ptr->row_position = ptr_a->row_position;
                ptr->column_position = ptr_a->column_position;
                ptr->value = ptr_a->value;
                Insert(result, ptr->row_position, ptr->column_position, ptr->value);
                ptr_a->next;
            }
            else {
                Node* ptr = *result;
                ptr->row_position = ptr_a->row_position;
                ptr->column_position = ptr_b->column_position;
                ptr->value = ptr_b->value;
                Insert(result, ptr->row_position, ptr->column_position, ptr->value);
                ptr_b->next;
            }
        }

    }

    while (ptr_a != NULL) {
        Node* ptr = *result;
        ptr->row_position = ptr_a->row_position;
        ptr->column_position = ptr_a->column_position;
        ptr->value = ptr_a->value;
        Insert(result, ptr->row_position, ptr->column_position, ptr->value);
        ptr_a->next;
    }

    while (ptr_b != NULL) {
        Node* ptr = *result;
        ptr->row_position = ptr_b->row_position;
        ptr->column_position = ptr_b->column_position;
        ptr->value = ptr_b->value;
        Insert(result, ptr->row_position, ptr->column_position, ptr->value);
        ptr_b->next;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `ptr_a->next;` and `ptr_b->next;` don't do anything. Did you intend to do anything?

Comment: `Add` can only return if both its arguments are the null pointer, and in that case `*result` is never modified.

Comment: Taking a step back: Why a linked list? A representation supporting addition could be (e.g.) a `some_map_container<std::tuple<size_t, size_t>, ValueType>` or some such. Then addition is a simple set union on the keys, with appropriate handling of the values for unique or overlapping keys. A linked list, if sorted by key, could also perform efficient addition by merger, but it would perform poorly when random matrix elements need modification. A map representation can do fast element modification as well as fast addition. Sorted tree maps can trade faster multiplication for slower addition etc.