# Adding two matrices constructed from linked list

Tags: c++, matrix

I have constructed two matrices using a struct from a [user answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506293/sparse-matrix-multiplication-using-linked-lists/77506424?noredirect=1#comment136643318_77506424) I received a while ago. I am trying to add the two matrices.

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    int row_position;
    int column_position;
    Node* next;
};

void Insert(Node** head, int row, int col, int value) {
    Node* new_node = new Node();
    new_node->value = value;
    new_node->row_position = row;
    new_node->column_position = col;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
```

```
void Add(Node* a, Node* b, Node** result) {
    Node* ptr_a, * ptr_b;
    
    for (ptr_a = a; ptr_a != nullptr; ptr_a = ptr_a->next) {
        for (ptr_b = b; ptr_b != nullptr; ptr_b = ptr_b->next) {
            int sum = ptr_a->value + ptr_b->value;
            Insert(result, ptr_a->row_position, ptr_a->column_position, sum);
        }
    }
}
```

This above addition function skips over any index where either matrix has zero as an element in it; e.g.

```
1 3
2 4

+

1 0
0 1
```

= [[2,0];[0,5]] when the answer should be [[2,3];[2,5]].

I suspect this is because I'm structuring the for loop to skip when ptr_a,ptr_b !=null but I may be very wrong.
I am using the following function to construct matrices from file inputs:

```
Node* ConstructMatrix(string filename, Node* a) {
    int rows_a, cols_a, rows_b, cols_b;
    string item_name;
    string dim;

    ifstream File1;
    File1.open(filename);

    if (!File1.is_open()) {
        cout << "Can't open .txt File." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::getline(File1, dim);
    if (dim.length() != 3) {
        cout << "dim.length() != 3 != 3" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        rows_a = dim[0] - '0';
        cols_a = dim[2] - '0';
    }
    cout << "rows_a,cols_a: " << rows_a << " " << cols_a << endl;
    int row_index = 0;
    while (std::getline(File1, item_name))
    {
        char str[252];
        strcpy(str, item_name.c_str());
        char* pch;
        char op = str[0];
        printf("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n", str);
        pch = strtok(str, " ");

        while (stoi(pch) != 0) {
            cout << "row index: " << row_index << endl;
            int col_index;
            int val;
            col_index = stoi(pch);
            pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
            val = stoi(pch);
            cout << "col_index,val=" << col_index << " " << val << endl;
            ReadMatrix(&a, row_index, cols_a, col_index, val);
            pch = strtok(NULL, " ");

        }
        row_index++;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return a;
    File1.close();
}
```

Contents of file:

```
2 2
1 1 0
2 1 0
```

(above example produces the following identity matrix):

```
1 0
0 1
```

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why custom linked list when you have to process a sparse matrix? This is so strange and not C++sy. Did you come up with this requirement or someone enforces this on you?

Comment: Try using `std::vector<std::map<int, int>>` to store matrix data.